# How to find the potential function of a vector field?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

[image]

I calculated that $\frac{dP}{dy} = \cos(y) = \frac{dQ}{dx}$

This tells me that the potential function exists, however I can't figure out what it is.

So far I have found that

$\frac{df}{dx} = \sin(y) + 2x \iff f = -x\cos(y) +x^2 + c(y)$

$\frac{df}{dy} = x\cos(y) + 1 \iff f = x\sin(y) = y + c(x)$

But I can't manage to link these two facts together and find out what f(x,y) is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when integrating

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \sin y + 2x, $$

you should get (just treat $y$ as a constant)

$$f  = x\sin y + x^2 + c(y), $$

differentiate this (with respect to $y$) gives

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x\cos y + c'(y) . $$

Comparing this to $Q = x\cos y +1$, we have

$$c'(y) = 1 \Rightarrow c(y) = y +C.$$

Thus you have

$$f(x, y) =  x\sin y + x^2 + y +C.$$

Comment: Thank you! I understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can find $f$ in one step by evaluating the integral $$\begin{align}
\int_0^1xP(xt,yt)+yQ(xt,yt)\;dt&=\int_0^1x(\sin yt+2xt)+y(xt\cos yt+1)\;dt \\
&=x\sin y+x^2+y
\end{align}$$plus a constant.

Comment: and what will this integral show for non-conservative fields?